# Hide View and preview from custom post types

Tags: custom-post-types

Is it possible to hide the ability to view or preview custom post types? I as, for custom post types like carousels and other forms that render in a particular way where viewing or previewing them out side their intended rendering purpose would not make any sense.

Comment: A similar question has some more versatile options: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/128636/how-to-disable-the-single-view-for-a-custom-post-type

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to set argument `public` to false at [register_post_type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type)() function.

> Whether a post type is intended to be used publicly either via the
>   admin interface or by front-end users. Default: false
>
> - 'false' - Post type is not intended to be used publicly and should    generally be unavailable in wp-admin and on the front end unless
>     explicitly planned for elsewhere.
> - 'true' - Post type is intended for    public use. This includes on the front end and in wp-admin.

Answer (score -1):

I did this by removing the `post_row_action`.

So, setup a function using that filter:

```
add_filter( 'post_row_actions', 'remove_view_link_cpt' );
function remove_view_link_cpt( $action ) {

    unset ($action['view']);
    return $action;
}
```

You will want to add a check to ensure you are on your CPT page when applying this code... otherwise it will remove the 'view' button from all post types.  You didn't mention this in your question.. so I can't make my answer more specific.

Answer (score -1):

If you are not going to view the posts on front-end set publicly_queryable to false

This will make the post updates without any view post link or preview changes button

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type