# 'publicly_queryable' => false not working as expected for custom post_type

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks

I have a custom post_type that I registered with the following settings:

```
  'labels' => piklist('post_type_labels', 'Tattooer')
  ,'title' => __('Enter the name of the tattooer')
  ,'supports' => array(
    'title',
    'editor',
    'thumbnail',
    'page-attributes'
  )
  ,'public' => true
  ,'has_archive' => true
  ,'rewrite' => array(
    'slug' => 'tattooer'
  )
  ,'publicly_queryable' => false
  ,'capability_type' => 'post'
  ,'edit_columns' => array(
    'title' => __('Name')
  )
  ,'hide_meta_box' => array(
    'author'
  )
```

I don't want any URLs to single `tattooer` posts. My understanding is that `'publicly_queryable' => false` is the tool for this job. But when I set it to `false`, the single URL is still active (Ex: /tattooer/foobar/) but redirects to the homepage. I think the intended behavior is that it should be a 404, which is what I want. What am I missing?

Notice that I'm using the wonderful [Piklist plugin](https://docs.piklist.com/actions-filters/filters/piklist_post_types/) to expedite the registration of custom post_type(s), but I've tested without it as well and the results were the same.

My information is based on [the documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/) and [this very similar question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/128636/how-to-disable-the-single-view-for-a-custom-post-type).

Comment: `rewrite` and `publicly_queryable` are in conflict with each other. You can't have rewrite rules for singular or archive views on a post type that's not publicly queryable.

Comment: Thanks @Milo. If I understand you correctly, setting `rewrite` to false should fix it?

Comment: @Milo That did not solve my problem. It changed the URL to a query var (ex: /?tattooer=some-body) but it still recognized the route and did not generate a 404.

Comment: Add any `/?nonsense_var=nonsense` to your root URL and note that those also don't generate 404s. Why is that a problem?

Comment: I want erroneous links to generate proper 404s instead of getting redirected to my home page.

Answer (score 12):

If you want archives, but not singular view, then `'publicly_queryable'` can't help you.

If you want that visiting a singular post send a 404... just do it.

You can hook `'template_redirect'` and manually set the 404:

```
add_action(
    'template_redirect',
    function () {
        if (is_singular('tattooer')) {
           global $wp_query;
           $wp_query->posts = [];
           $wp_query->post = null;
           $wp_query->set_404();
           status_header(404);
           nocache_headers();
        }
    }
);
```

Unfortunately there's no a function in WP to *force* 404, and you need to do it manually.

Comment: +1 seems to be the easiest way without having to create your own archive with the headache of handling pagination. OTOH can't you just register the post type with no front end access and add a rewrite rule for the archive?

Comment: @MarkKaplun That way you can obtain a archive + no singular, but if you are able to guess the singular URL (not that hard) whenever you try to access it you got a redirect to home page, not 404. If you _really_ want to obtain a 404 (lot of people don't like redirects from non-existent URLs) you have to stick with this. Also, register the rewrite rule is an action + a callback, not much different than code above, yes you can save a couple of lines of code, but you would need to flush rewrite rules... so I don't see that as a _simpler_ solution.

Comment: yeh, i assumed it is not simpler

Comment: Thanks. I don't need the archives either. The content only appears on one page with a custom (WP_Query) loop. So it literally has no routes (accept the admin interfaces).

Comment: @emersonthis than you should also set `has_archive` to `false`. And by also setting both `publicly_queryable` and `rewrite` to `false` as well, that should be fine. At that point the code I proposed should be removed and that's it. Yes, some people can go to the URL ` /?tattooer=xxx` but that in your site is non-sensical query var appended to home page URL, and it is ok it does not 404, that's default behavior of WP (and does not affect SEO, if you are wondering).

Comment: @emersonthis basically if the CPT is not publicly queriable, when you visit an URL like `example.com?tattooer=xxx` the URL is **not redirecting to home page**, it is literally **pointing to home page** by _also_ adding a query var that the application is not able to parse. Sending a 404 error whenever an arbitrary, nonsensical query var is added to the URL provides no benefit at all: not for SEO, not for performance, not for security, not for anything else. So... why bother?