# Redirect Single Post CPT (Custom Post Type) to a specific URL

Tags: custom-post-types, multisite, single

I have a domain `domain.com` and subdomain `materials.domain.com`

At the `domain.com` scope, I created a custom post type called `resources` and a portfolio grid (using Elementor) to display it's featured image with the title.

When clicking on the grid item, the **single** post is shown for example: `domain.com/resources/resource-title`

I'd like to remove the **single** post from the domain and redirect on click to `materials.domain.com/resource-title`. I already have this page on the `materials`subdomain).

How can I achieve that?

Comment: How are you generating the grid item?  Please add that code to your question.

Comment: I'm using elementor portfolio widget to display resource archive CPT as grid

Comment: So you need a redirect so that browsing to `domain.com/resources/resource-title` redirects you immediately to `materials.domain.com/resource-title` ?

Comment: Yes. If possible I want to disable the single from the CPT at domain.com and when click on the grid Item, access materials.domain.com/resource-title (in practice if I can be able to setu up a custom destiny url at domain.com works too).

Comment: I read at this [thread](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/128636/how-to-disable-the-single-view-for-a-custom-post-type) how redirect the single. Any idea how can I pass a custom url to the function? (maybe using custom fields?)

Comment: Is materials.domain.com the same Wordpress website? I'd be tempted to use .htaccess to do this so the browser gets redirected before it hits Wordpress at all

Comment: I'm using a wordpress multisite installation and nignx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sometimes this would be achievable with `add_rewrite_url` but it looks like in this case it's not as you need to redirect to a different domain.

In this case you need .htaccess or nginx rules to do this, so you need to add something like this to your nginx config **for domain.com only**, in order to rewrite those URLs:

`rewrite ^/resources/(.+) https://materials.domain.com/$1 permanent;`

You'll likely need to restart nginx after you add this to the config file.

Happy to help if this doesn't do exactly what you want. There's more examples of nginx rewrite rules here: https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2017/08/nginx-rewrite-examples/

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it from WordPress environment itself..

```
function wpse370481_redirect_url() {
    if ( is_singular( 'resources' ) ) {
        global $post;
    
        $path = $post->post_name;
        
        $redirect_url = 'https://materials.domain.com/' . $path;
        
        wp_redirect( $redirect_url );
        exit;
            
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wpse370481_redirect_url' );
```

Havn't tested this code as I currently don't have a setup to test this, but in theory, the code should work.

Comment: This will not work if the custom post type is declared with `'publicly_queriable'=>false` (which you'd want to do to prevent it from appearing in sitemaps).