# Custom post type: Disable single page, but keep archive

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-post-type-archives

I am looking for the best way to create custom post-types which are only used as an archive for their posts. As an example I want an archive showing all employees of a company, but I don't want the employees to have a singular page. This is a use-case that I stumbled upon various times, but never found the perfect solution.

The main requirements are:

- disable the singular view of posts;
- be able to use archive.php of the theme as the archive page;
- remove links to the singular view from WordPress.

All methods that I've found are not able to tick all the requirements above.

By setting a filter with a `template_redirect` for the single page, the links to the singular pages are still being shown in WordPress (and probably in sitemaps and such), which is confusing for the end-user.

By setting `publicly_queryable` to `false` the links in the back-end are removed, but so is the `archive` page, even though `has_archive` is set to `true`. This can be solved by creating a page with a page template that loads the posts from the post-type. But that's not ideal either.

Comment: Try this one:  https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/319465/60844

Comment: @TonyDjukic Yes, I tried this one before and it mostly solves the problem. The only thing is that WordPress is still showing the 'view' buttons in the post-type overview. Also slugs are still registered for the posts, which is unneeded but that's not a real problem for me.

Comment: The solution found here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/403951/14064 met the above requirements. Other "correct" solutions set the `query_vars` value to false but as of this comment this no longer works.

Answer (score 0):

I've 'fixed' my problem with the code below. This is a function that checks the post-type settings. If `query_var` has been set to `false`, the view button is removed from the post-type archive in the back-end.

For my use-case, this solves the problem. There are no links to the posts anymore.

The reason why both `post_row_actions` and `page_row_actions` is being used, is because post-types with `hierarchical` set to `false` are running through the first one, otherwise trough the second one.

```
function modify_list_row_actions( $actions, $post ) {
    // Retrieve the post-type object
    $post_type_object = get_post_type_object(get_post_type($post));

    // check if query_var has been set to 'false'
    if ($post_type_object->query_var == false) {
        // if so, removing the 'view' link
        unset($actions['view']);
    }

    return $actions;
}
add_filter( 'post_row_actions', 'modify_list_row_actions', 10, 2);
add_filter( 'page_row_actions', 'modify_list_row_actions', 10, 2);
```